# Create a link to redirect to the Web site Controller ActionResult from Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I need to send an email to the user for **resetting password**. Which contains a link to open the Password Reset page in Web site.
Both website & web api are in same domain.But different solutions.

I have created a link in web api.

```
var callbackUrl = Url.Link("ResetPassword", new { Controller = "Account", code = token });
```

But when it tested on postman it shows *'ResetPassword' could not be found in the route collection.*
There is ResetPassword ActionResult in Account controller of Website.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route(Name="ResetPassword")]
public ActionResult ResetPassword(string code)
{
     return code == null ? View("Error") : View();
}
```

The `RegisterRoutes` method is,

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

I have not yet deployed the solution.
Will it work on deployment?

Comment: Can you share `RegisterRoutes` method too?

Comment: Can you share the folder structure of hosting?

Comment: @BikashSinghMaharjan `RegisterRoutes` method shared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've basically misplaced **Route name** with **Action name**. Please try to use this:

```
var callbackUrl = Url.Link("Default", new { Controller = "Account", Action ="ResetPassword", code = token });
```

Comment: Glad for you :) Thanks